# How can I make my modified radio buttons tabbable?

Tags: html, css, tabindex

I've used some CSS to make mobile-friendly 'radio' buttons by hiding the `input`s and using the `label` elements instead. The code is below, but I've made a [jsFiddle for convenience](http://jsfiddle.net/xNj9z/1/).

My problem is that a major usability issue arises when using a keyboard to navigate the form: the fields are no longer tabbable. I've tried adding `tabindex` attributes to the hidden `input`s, the `labels` and to the `div`. The first two do not work at all, adding `tabindex` to the div works (the div is highlighted), but I can't interact with the form elements at all (with the arrow keys for example).

Is it possible to fix this just with CSS/HTML? I'd rather not fall back to javascript, but if there's no other way I guess I'll have to.

```
<input type='text'>
<div class='radio-select'>
  <input checked="checked" id="no" name="yes_no" value="False" type="radio">
  <label for="no">
    No
  </label>
  <input id="yes" name="yes_no" value="True" type="radio">
  <label for="yes" >
    Yes
  </label>
</div>
<input type='text'>
<style>
.radio-select label{
    background: #f00;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:5px 0;
    max-width:200px;
    clear:both;
    display: block;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.radio-select input[type='radio']{
    display: none;
}
.radio-select input[type='radio']:checked + label{
    background:#0f0 !important;
}
.radio-select input[type='radio']:checked + label:before{
    content:"✔";
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you hide the `input`s by setting their opacity to 0 they will still be tabbable:

```
.radio-select input[type='radio']{
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    position:absolute
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xNj9z/4/)

Comment: This focuses them, yes, but doesn't actually select them. I could add some javascript to do that, but it's not really ideal.

Comment: You shouldn't set your radio button's display to none, you should set their opacity to 0 so they are not visible but tabbable and selectable through the keyboard.

Comment: @TomMedley, I've updated the code. Now you can tab through the label tags with arrow keys.

Comment: In my page (minimal: just some `<input type="radio" />` in `<label>` without any `tabindex="0"` attributes on any elements and no CSS/styles at all) and I see that the radio inputs cannot be focused with the Tab key at all. Are you sure this works?