# How to use keyboard tab on hidden radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-experience

Within a form I have the following generic html:

```html
<input type="text" autofocus placeholder="Full name" />

<input name="yesno" type="radio" value="Yes" id="yes">
<label for="yes">Yes</label>

<input name="yesno" type="radio" value="No" id="no">
<label for="no">No</label>
```

In this form I can <kbd>TAB</kbd> from the text `input` into the radio buttons and select "Yes" or "No" using the left / right keys.

I then apply some styling to make the radio buttons conform with the design:

```css
input[type="text"] {
  height: 60px;
  text-indent: 1em;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]+label {
  color: #106AA2;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  border: 1px solid #C5DBE8;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background: linear-gradient(#1275B2, #106AA2);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" autofocus placeholder="Full name" />

<input name="yesno" type="radio" value="Yes" id="yes">
<label for="yes">Yes</label>

<input name="yesno" type="radio" value="No" id="no">
<label for="no">No</label>
```

However, I can now no longer <kbd>TAB</kbd> from the text `input` to the radio buttons. I am aware this is because I have `display:none`d them.

Is there a cross-browser way to enable a user to <kbd>TAB</kbd> onto these radio buttons?

Ideally I am looking for a solution that is pure CSS, however I am open to a javascript solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956962/making-my-hidden-radio-buttons-tabbable-508-compliant

Comment: Hey did you try my answer ? :)

Comment: I did. I like the use of `outline` to indicate when the radio buttons were being selected. I have chosen to go with @chbchb55 s answer as the `position:relative` approach altered the gap between the elements more than I was looking for.

Comment: Cool, Thanks for replying :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Don't make it non-existent with `display: none;` just shrink it.

You can just set the `width` and `height` to `0` to make the input not visible but functional with tabbing.

```css
input[type="text"] {
  height: 60px;
  text-indent: 1em;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: solid 1px lightblue;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  /* display: none; */
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

input[type="radio"]+label {
  color: #106AA2;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  border: 1px solid #C5DBE8;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background: linear-gradient(#1275B2, #106AA2);
  color: #fff;
}

input[type="radio"]:focus+label {
  outline: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" autofocus placeholder="Full name" />

<input name="yesno" type="radio" value="Yes" id="yes">
<label for="yes">Yes</label>

<input name="yesno" type="radio" value="No" id="no">
<label for="no">No</label>
```

Comment: Did you actually run and test your code prior to posting an answer? `I can now no longer TAB from the text input to the radio buttons.`, try tabbing, it doesn't work.

Comment: I can, but you still have to use the arrow keys to switch between individual radios

Comment: It works. Did you actually run it prior to commenting? It just doesn't seem like it is in focus that's all

Comment: @Alex Press tab once and then using arrow keys makes it work. Though it should be done for the first time also

Comment: It works with left and right buttons but how about the initial tab?

Comment: You can't comment css with `//`

Comment: Lol, my bad, will fix

Comment: Note, this will break things if you just change `display: none` to making it a small size, especially if this component is within a flexbox or other component with gaps. You need to also add something like `position: absolute` to take it out of the layout flow.

Answer (score 2):

Radio buttons aren't "tabbable" as such. You need to use the keyboard arrows to change the radio selected. This is expected behaviour when it comes to accessibility. What I would advise however, would be to give a visual representation of what radio is selected (as you have already done with the labels).

This is all that's required.

```
input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

This is the final answer below

```css
input[type="text"] {
  height: 60px;
  text-indent: 1em;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

input[type="radio"]+label {
  color: #106AA2;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  border: 1px solid #C5DBE8;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background: linear-gradient(#1275B2, #106AA2);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" autofocus placeholder="Full name" />

<input name="yesno" type="radio" value="Yes" id="yes">
<label for="yes">Yes</label>

<input name="yesno" type="radio" value="No" id="no">
<label for="no">No</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't hide the radio buttons, cover them with the labels instead using relative position with negative left value

And add custom CSS for focus styles on label. Updated CSS

```
input[type="radio"]:focus+label {
  outline: 2px dotted red;
}

input[type="radio"]+label {
  color: #106AA2;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  border: 1px solid #C5DBE8;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
}
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
  height: 60px;
  text-indent: 1em;
}

input[type="radio"]:focus+label {
  outline: 2px dotted red;
}

input[type="radio"]+label {
  color: #106AA2;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  border: 1px solid #C5DBE8;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background: linear-gradient(#1275B2, #106AA2);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" autofocus placeholder="Full name" />


<input name="yesno" type="radio" value="Yes" id="yes">
<label for="yes">Yes</label>



<input name="yesno" type="radio" value="No" id="no">
<label for="no">No</label>
```